# Non-type template argument narrowing in template recursion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code, which is supposed to calculate the number of bits in a byte at compile time.

```
template<unsigned char c, size_t I>
struct char_bit
{
    static constexpr size_t get() noexcept {
        return c > 0 ? char_bit<c << 1, I + 1>::get() : I
    }
};

int main()
{   
    std::cout << char_bit<1, 0>::get();
}
```

By passing in `1` to the `unsigned char` parameter, I'm expecting to get a final result of 8 as it will shift left 8 times until the char becomes 0.

However, compiling with Clang 3.7.1, I get a compilation error:

> error: non-type template argument evaluates to 256, which cannot be
>   narrowed to type 'unsigned char' [-Wc++11-narrowing]

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried: char_bit<(c << 1) & 0xFF, I + 1>::get()   or    char_bit<(unsigned char)(c << 1), I + 1>::get()  ?

Comment: @SvenNilsson Why on Earth do those both work?

Comment: @SvenNilsson I wouldn't do the first because it would limit the size of a byte to 8 bit. Today this sounds legit but heh, you never know. Besides that goes against the spirit the OP's goal.

Comment: Yeah, they work because they limit the value to max 255 I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to avoid this error is to go in reverse: instead of overflowing your char, you start with the maximum and right-shift until you hit zero. You will need a specialisation to make the code work (you will have needed it in either case anyway):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<unsigned char c, size_t I>
struct char_bit
{
    static constexpr size_t get() noexcept {
        return char_bit< (c >> 1), I + 1>::get();
    }
};

template<size_t I>
struct char_bit<0, I>
{
    static constexpr size_t get() noexcept {
        return I;
    }
};


int main()
{   
    constexpr unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(-1);
    std::cout << char_bit<c, 0>::get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a standard macro for that:

```
#include <climits>

int main() {
    std:cout << CHAR_BIT << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OP said this works, so I'm posting it as answer:

```
char_bit<(unsigned char)(c << 1), I + 1>::get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happens. But I think, you can fix it using template function specialization.

```
template<unsigned char c, size_t I>
struct char_bit
{
    static constexpr size_t get() noexcept {
        return char_bit<(c << 1), I + 1>::get();
    }
};

template <size_t I>
struct char_bit<0, I>
{
    static constexpr size_t get() noexcept { return I; }
};
```